# What is the proper way to check if an Iterator is complete?

Tags: crystal-lang

As the title states, I'd like to know the proper way to check if an iterator is complete.

I couldn't find anything in the docs but I found something like this in the [source](https://github.com/manastech/crystal/blob/e363b63c05abc63fc11c407c23507ff144900c45/src/iterator.cr#L96):

```
iter.next.is_a? Iterator::Stop
```

Toy example:

```
a = "a世c"
b = a.each_char

puts b.next # a
puts b.next # 世
puts b.next # c
puts b.next # #<Iterator::Stop:0x8ccbff8>

if b.next.is_a? Iterator::Stop
  puts "DONE" # successfully prints DONE
end
```

Is this correct and proper or is there a different way I should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the proper way. But most of the time you don't need to deal with `next`, you just chain iterators and get a result out of them.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I'm just porting some code and so I'm doing direct conversion as much as possible and will likely refactor later.